# Bind data(array) to repeator control in jquery

Tags: c#, jquery

I have data in array(key value) i need to bind array to asp:repeater control based on ID in jquery.
i tried 
var filterIPs = new Array("empid","empname");
    i have values in array for empid and empname

```
$("#ipRepeater").Datasource = filterIPs;
$("#ipRepeater").DataBind();
```

but it is not working.
   Let me know can i bind in client side(jquery) not server side

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET controls are *server side*, so they are rendered on server.
jQuery is client-side, so it works in client's browser.

You cannot set Repeater's DataSource property from jQuery since it happens on different ends.

Use client-side lists to display data you get on the client side.